# Python Like File Independence For c++

Tags: c++, ide, debugging, github

**Background:**

I have been using python for doing various problems from Codeforces and have been using github as a version control. For python I used **pycharm**, there I created a project and for new question all I had to do is to create a new python file -  do the problem - save it and commit it. But recently I switched to c++ and started using **Clion**

**Problem:**

1. Soon I found out that in the same project I cannot create different files for different problems and just run/execute them. And I have to create new project for each of them.
2. Also I am having troubling using debugging option of Clion

**Expected Solutions:**

1. IDE or online IDE that can help me create separate independent files (cpp files) in same project/folder which I can sync with github.
2. IDE which can help debug.

**NOTE:** Problem 1 is priority. And for some reason I get Down vote please make sure to comment about the reason.